# Value of type 'Result<String>' has no member 'error' [Alamofire, Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift5

As Swift 5 introduced **Result** type, so I am getting numerous errors with Alamofire.

**Other Errors:**

```
Enum case 'success' has no associated values
Member 'failure' in 'Result<T>' produces result of type 'Result<String>', but context expects 'Result<T>'
```

Any quick fix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Result
```

to

```
Alamofire.Result
```

Or create a `typealias` as,

```
typealias AFResult = Alamofire.Result
```

and change `Result` to `AFResult`.

Comment: You can see the same issue [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2752) and how they handled. This should be fixed in coming version of `Alamofire` so for now you can use `Alamofire.Result`